# Pointers to closest portals don't show up

Tags: ingress

I have two phones I play Ingress with. On one, when no portals are displayed in the main view, the closest two or three portals are indicated by little “‹distance› to *this* portal” tags. On the other phone (almost the same display size+resolution), these don't show up under any circumstances.
[image]

Thus, what controls these tags? How do I turn them on?

Comment: What  phones/OS do you use? By the way, as far as i know it's not allowed to play 2 accounts. If I was you, I wouldn't risk to get banned on a level 13 account. Or are you using just 2 phones with the same account? Thats not a big deal, but can also cause trouble if you switch phones too often. Some friends had this problem.

Comment: No I do NOT play with two accounts, and I'm careful to terminate the client on phone A before I start it on phone B (actually it terminates itself because the battery runs out).

Comment: The phones both run CyanogenMod 12 (LG Optimus G, Samsung S5).

Comment: For me that often happens when the network is very slow. Mostly in public transport.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your zoom level, phone hardware, internet connection, etc. Just make sure you have the configuration option enabled and play with your zoom level.